# fully change html element to another using javascript <button>NEXT</button> to <input type="submit">

Tags: javascript, html

I have a multi part form in which: when the user fills each page and clicks on a next button given below. When on last page, the next button changes to a submit element but I am not able to submit data to database(MySQL XAMPP) I need input type="submit"  instead of a button.  I want to change all buttons to input type submit. My script is given below:

**HTML for button**

```
<div style="float:right;">
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
    <button type="button" name="submit1" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
function showTab1(n) {
    // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    x[n].style.display = "block";
    //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
    if (n == 0) {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit Form";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the submit()-function you want to call and the nextPrev()-function.

Comment: @batman Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. Updating this question with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help people trying to answer this question understand the problem better. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Add an input element under your button style="display: none;" and give it an id="js-submit-form"

```
    <div style="float:right;">
        <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
        <button type="button" name="submit1" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
        <input type="submit" id="js-submit-form" name="submit" value="Submit Form" style="display: none;">
    </div>
```

Then I set display:none for #nextBtn and display:block for #js-submit-form

```
function showTab(n) {

 // This function will display the specified tab of the form ...
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
 x[n].style.display = "block";

 // ... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
 if (n == 0) {
  document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
 } else {
  document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
 }

 if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
  document.getElementById("nextBtn").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("js-submit-form").style.display = "inline";
} else {
  document.getElementById("nextBtn").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("js-submit-form").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
}

 // ... and run a function that displays the correct step indicator:
 fixStepIndicator(n)
```

}

Then Style the input as you wish. Hope that helped ;-)

Just for information this multi part form was created by [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp)

Answer (score 0):

First change the `button` element to a `input` type button element:

```
<div style="float:right;">
    <input type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="submit1" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)" value="Next" />
</div>
```

Then in Javascript you can change the `type` of the submit button to `submit`:

```
function showTab1(n) {
    // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    x[n].style.display = "block";
    //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
    if (n == 0) {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
    }
    var nextBtn = document.getElementById("nextBtn");
    if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
        nextBtn.setAttribute('value', 'Submit Form');
        nextBtn.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
        nextBtn.removeAttribute('onclick');
    } else {
        nextBtn.setAttribute('value', 'Next');
        nextBtn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    }
}
```

Be aware that you also have to remove or change the `onclick` attribute of the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

I created what I think is a working snippet of your code…
I think the best approach is to use another element for the submit.
So, I added a hidden submit button, which shows when necessary.

Is that what you wanted to achieve?

See my comments in the code:

```js
// Added this vars here
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
var prev = document.getElementById("prevBtn");
var next = document.getElementById("nextBtn");
var subm = document.getElementById("submBtn"); // New button
var n = 0;

function nextPrev(i) { // Renamed your function

  // Added: Hide all tabs
  for (var j = 0; j < tabs.length; j++) {
    tabs[n].style.display = "none";
  }

  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  n = n + i;
  tabs[n].style.display = "block";

  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    prev.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    prev.style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (tabs.length - 1)) {
    next.style.display = "none";
    subm.style.display = "inline";
  } else {
    next.style.display = "inline";
    subm.style.display = "none";
  }
}

nextPrev(0); // Launch the function on load
```

```css
.tab {
  display: none;
}

#submBtn {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form><!-- Added form -->
  <div style="float:right;">
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
    <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    <!-- Added this button -->
    <button type="submit" name="submit1" id="submBtn">Submit Form</button>
  </div>
  <!-- Added tabs -->
  <div class="tab">tab 0</div>
  <div class="tab">tab 1</div>
  <div class="tab">tab 2</div>
  <div class="tab">tab 3</div>
</form>
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

**The `disabled` property**

Instead of showing/hide elements, you could use the `disabled` property.
Here is the same code using it:

```js
// Added this vars here
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
var prev = document.getElementById("prevBtn");
var next = document.getElementById("nextBtn");
var subm = document.getElementById("submBtn"); // New button
var n = 0;

function nextPrev(i) { // Renamed your function

  // Added: Hide all tabs
  for (var j = 0; j < tabs.length; j++) {
    tabs[n].style.display = "none";
  }

  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  n = n + i;
  tabs[n].style.display = "block";

  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    prev.disabled = true;
  } else {
    prev.disabled = false;
  }
  if (n == (tabs.length - 1)) {
    next.disabled = true;
    subm.disabled = false;
  } else {
    next.disabled = false;
    subm.disabled = true;
  }
}

nextPrev(0); // Launch the function on load
```

```css
.tab {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form><!-- Added form -->
  <div style="float:right;">
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
    <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    <!-- Added this button -->
    <button type="submit" name="submit1" id="submBtn">Submit Form</button>
  </div>
  <!-- Added tabs -->
  <div class="tab">tab 0</div>
  <div class="tab">tab 1</div>
  <div class="tab">tab 2</div>
  <div class="tab">tab 3</div>
</form>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

On last form you add a type attribute to button element. Like this

```
function showTab1(n) {
    // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    x[n].style.display = "block";
    //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
    if (n == 0) {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").setAttribute("type", "submit");
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit Form";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
    }
}
```